# I need help understanding how to put a smaller image on another large image

Tags: c

I need help understanding how to put a smaller image on another large image. The small image should be ten pixels from the right edge and ten from the bottom edge. now I get four of the small picture in the big picture. In the picture one I want to achieve but I get as picture two. Here is the code Can anyone explain how I do?

```
int i = mainWidth - (waterWidth + 10);
int j = mainHeigt - (waterHeigt + 10);

for (int y = 0; y <= waterHeigt; y++)
{
    int start_pos = (i + (j * mainWidth)) * mainChannel;

    for (int x = 0; x <= waterWidth; x++)
    {

        int test = start_pos + ((x + (y * mainWidth)));

        newImage[test] = waterStamp[((x + y * waterWidth) * waterChannel)];

    }

}

stbi_write_jpg("Test.jpg", mainHeigt, mainWidth,`enter code here`waterChannel, newImage, 100);

stbi_image_free(waterStamp);
free(mainImg);
free(newImage);
```

}

[image: The one on the left I want to achieve but I get like the one on the rightenter code here`]

Comment: What is `waterChannel`?

Comment: Its the RGBA for the smap pic

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a [mcve]. There are too many missing pieces of information in the code.

Comment: Pick an image manipulation library and use it. Don't try and do this by bashing around in just C with no libraries, you'll waste a ton of time to support even something simple like BMP format.

Comment: I use stb_image

Comment: I'll try one more time. After the two calls to `stbi_load`, if you `printf("%d %d\n", waterChannel, mainChannel);` what do you get?

Comment: printf("%d %d\n", waterChannel, mainChannel);   I get  3 and 3

Comment: You forgot to multiply by `mainChannel` when computing `test`. And the loops should be using less than `<` instead of less than or equal `<=`.

Comment: And the code is only copying one byte per pixel when it needs to copy three.

Comment: the problem is start_pos this is where i want the new image to start. The first line of waterImage is overwritten on newImage. But when y increases, it starts writing the same line it wrote at the beginning.

Comment: I just want the red color only

Answer (score 0):

Since the small image isn't appearing where it's supposed to, the bug is likely related to the destination index, `test`, when writing it into the bigger image. It looks like:

- In `test = start_pos + ((x + (y * mainWidth)))`, the `((x + (y * mainWidth)))` part should be multiplied by mainChannel.
- The loop condition over x should be `x < waterWidth` instead of with `<=`. Same comment for the loop over y.

Comment: I did so `int test = start_pos + ((x + (y * mainWidth)) * mainChannel);` and still does not work. The The first loop then is `y = 0` and` x` goes from 0 - 511 and `start_pos` is the pixel the loop should start at. The first race that goes over `x` is correct, but when` Y = 1` it happens that the image starts in a different position instead of starting under the first bixel.

Comment: There could be other bugs besides the couple I mentioned. If I understand your comment correctly, the smaller image is now appearing sheared?---each row is translated relative to the previous row? Double check how `test` is computed, particularly the factor on `y`. To line the rows up, you want that `test` advances by the row stride `mainWidth * mainChannel` with each increment of `y`.